# Cannot create dbset for openiddict

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, openid-connect, .net-5

Error:

```
Cannot create a DbSet for 'OpenIddictEntityFrameworkCoreApplication' because this type is not included in the model for the context.
```

I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54783658/cannot-create-a-dbset-for-openiddictapplication-because-this-type-is-not-inclu).

However, this solution does not work for .NET 5.0?

Missing reference to OpenIddictApplication" , OpenIddictAuthorization , OpenIddictScope, OpenIddictToken?

---

- OpenIddict.AspNetCore" Version="3.0.0-beta6.20527.75
- OpenIddict.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0-beta6.20527.75

---

```
public class ApiHubContext : DbContext
{
    public ApiHubContext(DbContextOptions options)
        : base(options) { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        builder.UseOpenIddict<ApplicationClient, ApplicationAuthorization, ApplicationScope, ApplicationToken, long>();
    }
}

public class ApplicationClient : OpenIddictApplication<long, ApplicationAuthorization, ApplicationToken>
{

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public string Remarks { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationAuthorization : OpenIddictAuthorization<long, ApplicationClient, ApplicationToken> { }
public class ApplicationScope : OpenIddictScope<long> { }
public class ApplicationToken : OpenIddictToken<long, ApplicationClient, ApplicationAuthorization> { }
```

Comment: Define "*does not seem to work*"

Comment: Missing reference "OpenIddictApplication" , OpenIddictAuthorization , OpenIddictScope, OpenIddictToken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These entities have been renamed in 3.0. You can find the complete list here: https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/tree/dev/src/OpenIddict.EntityFrameworkCore.Models